# Switch statement strings matching but not functioning

Tags: c#, arrays, string, tcp, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that uses a string converted from a char[] that was sent over a data stream from a server to the client. The code is client-side.

The default case is always hit even though the server and the default error code is always matching cases exactly.

```
SERVER SIDE
private void SendToClient(string message, TcpAccount account)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            account.TcpClient.GetStream().WriteAsync(buffMessage, 0, buffMessage.Length);
            log.AppendText(string.Format("Message {0} sent to account {1}", message, account.ID));
            log.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch
        {
            log.AppendText(string.Format("Message {0} sent to account {1}", message, account.ID));
            log.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

CLIENT SIDE
public async void ReadDataAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            char[] buff = new char[64];
            int readByteCount = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                readByteCount = await clientStreamReader.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);

                if (readByteCount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from server.");
                    client.Close();
                    break;
                }
                string code = new string(buff);
                ProcessServerCode(code);
                Array.Clear(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

public void ProcessServerCode(string code)
    {
        switch (code)
        {
            case "regcom":
                MessageBox.Show("Registration Complete");
                break;

            case "logcom":
                MessageBox.Show("Login Complete");
                break;

            case "badpass":
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
                break;

            case "badaccount":
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Account");
                break;

            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown Code: " + code);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I can't get it off the default code.

Also, since I'm new to client/server and socket programming, I just realized the server sends a byte[] but the client receives a char[]. Is there any conflict there? Any particular reason for this (since I'm using those particular pieces of code from an online training session)?

Comment: Did you try to debug what the client code receives? If you always hit the default then your input is not what do you expect it to be

Comment: You can try to trim the received string, update this line `string code = new string(buff).Trim();`. I think this can be a reason, because you wait to receive 64 bytes, but received string is less in your examples

Comment: side note: **never ever** use `async void`. Even if you don't care about the result, you should **always** use `async Task`. A key reason here is that `async` cares about sync-context, and many sync-contexts exist that **actively block** `async void` - in particular, but not limited to, the ASP.NET sync-context. This means that you can find code works fine in one system, and doesn't work **at all** when you change version/platform/etc, because of sync-context differences (one allowing `async void`, one not allowing it). So: **never ever** use `async void`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks! I have made the changes and will be sure to avoid async void in the future.

Comment: another side note: you aren't actually `await`-ing the `WriteAsync` - you **really should** await that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you're ignoring `readByteCount` (which is actually a character count, not a byte count); you *should* use:

```
string code = new string(buff, 0, readByteCount);
```

However, the next problem I see is that you don't have any framing protocol. This means:

- if two messages are sent close together, you could receive what appears to be a single concatenated value
- even individual values could be arbitrarily truncated as they get split between packets
- etc

In either case:

- if the message is longer than your buffer length, you're broken
- if you ever receive more than one message at a time, you're broken

as in either case, it'll never be possible to recover the position correctly. Hence: frames, where each frame is a complete message.

A common approach with text-based protocols is to use a newline as a frame (I'll let you decide whether that means CR, LF, CRLF, etc); then you can just use `ReadLine` / `ReadLineAsync` on the text reader, and it'll *do it all automatically*, so:

```
string code = await clientStreamReader.ReadLineAsync();
if (code is null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from server.");
    client.Close();
}
else
{
    ProcessServerCode(code);
}
```

Comment: ("and it'll do it all automatically" > as long as you don't forget to escape line ends in payload...)

Comment: @PatrickHofman indeed :) actually, if I was being pedantic I'd have said "avoid using a `TextReader` in a socket server - deal with the frames manually, only decode when you have entire frames, and ideally use something like 'pipelines' as the engine", but that would take a *lot* more explaining than I can manage on a Monday...

Comment: @MarcGravell So focusing on the first issue, changing the code to to your first line gave me the same result. The default shows that I receive "regcom" as the code, but again it doesn't technically match the "regcom" case somehow. To the eye they match, but somehow in the code they don't match.

As for your other notes, that all seems way out of my scope (I'm really new to any kind of network communication), but using the method ReadLineAsync(), the client no longer receives ANY message from the server successfully. Is there some other change I need on the server side?

Comment: @Arcaster yes, the frames need to match at both ends; the simplest fix would be `byte[] buffMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "\r\n");` (but more efficient approaches are possible)

Comment: @Arcaster as for the "changing the code to to your first line" issue; unfortunately, to diagnose further I'd really need to look byte-by-byte, plus that approach is doomed to failure *anyway* because of the framing problem - so I'm not sure it is worth either of our time trying to take that further

Comment: @MarcGravell Ultimately switching to ReadLineAsync() and adding the line break in the message solved my issue. As for the problems with the foundation, this being a personal learning project and not production-grade code, I'll tackle any complications down the road. Thanks for the heads up and solution.